# setTimeout in a callback function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Can someone find a problem in the code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#leftsettingswindow").on("keyup", "#fontsize2", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var txtVal = this.value;
            $('#content').css("font-size", txtVal + "%");
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

this works flawlessly,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#leftsettingswindow").on("keyup", "#fontsize2", function () {

            var txtVal = this.value;
            $('#content').css("font-size", txtVal + "%");

    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the console error message?

Comment: still no resizing happening even after changing this.value; to your suggestion

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
2
Uncaught  TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is not a local variable, so it isn't saved in the closure. You need to bind a local variable to it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#leftsettingswindow").on("keyup", "#fontsize2", function () {
        var savedThis = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            var txtVal = savedThis.value;
            $('#content').css("font-size", txtVal + "%");
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` does not invoke in the same scope. So `this` is not the same `this` as in your 2nd example.

```
...
var self = this;

setTimeout(function () {
  var txtVal = self.value;
  $('#content').css("font-size", txtVal + "%");
}, 3000);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Barmar who answered this on another thread.

"this" is not a local variable, so it isn't saved in the closure. You need to bind a local variable to it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#leftsettingswindow").on("keyup", "#fontsize2", function () {
        var savedThis = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
        var txtVal = savedThis.value;
            $('#content').css("font-size", txtVal + "%");
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In code snippet, "this.value" returns "undefined" after 3 secs.

So, use selector, instead of this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#leftsettingswindow").on("keyup", "#fontsize2", function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      var txtVal = $('#fontsize2').val();
      $('#content').css("font-size", txtVal + "%");
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```